# "Looking for a job" box doesn't show the Visa Sponsor tag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I noticed *Looking for a job* box doesn't show the *Visa Sponsor* tag even though the job ad specifically mentions the company sponsors visa.

Is this a bug or intentional behavior?

**Job Ad**
[image: Job Ad]

---

**Looking for a job box**
[image: Looking for a job box]

Comment: I wouldn't call this a bug, because there's just not that much space available, and it's likely just a decision not to show this. You might consider retagging this as a feature request, and proposing why and where you'd like to see this.

Comment: But that's like one of the key things for many people to consider applying for a company and imo if the company provides it, it has to be shown in that box as well; plus, I'm pretty sure it was there before, right in front of the relocation tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We only show "Visa Sponsorship" on an ad when the job listing is outside your current country (based on IP address). We know it's not perfect, because even some people in the country need visa sponsorship in order to work there. However, for most people, it would be noise, and would distract from more important elements of the ad.